# How to draw complex SVGs within a Flutter Application?

Tags: javascript, flutter, svg, rendering

I am developing an application with Flutter that involves render, and then interacting with, an svg-encoded piece of sheet music.  Specifically, I need to be able to draw and re-draw quickly, and get the id attribute of whatever element is under any mouse events.  Doing this in a Javascript environment (not in Flutter) is quite easy and just requires adding in the svg to a , and attaching a mouse listener.

The specific problem that I am running into in Flutter is that none of the svg libraries support the kinds of features that this sheet music encoding scheme uses (nested  tag,  tag, , , overflow attributes, etc).  So my question is, what can I do to get this kind of svg rendering?  And does that still allow for determining the element that is under a mouse event?

I imagine that converting the svg to an image (png, jpeg, etc) is too slow, and that would require re-rendering the image to a different resolution when the user scrolls.  What options exist?  Is there a way to define a different drawing solution for each platform I want to use?  I hope to port my application to Desktop (primary platform), Web (in a limited capacity), and perhaps Mobile.

I have tried the following libraries in flutter's pub dev:
flutter_svg
jovial_svg

Neither of them were able to render any kind of image from my svg file.  Though I got both to work with a simple svg file (an example dart icon)

Thanks for any suggestions and help!

More information:

My system: Windows 64
Flutter 3.16.9
Dart 3.2.6
Engine: revision 41456452f2

(Svg files being rendered dynamically by the c++ open-source library Verovio)

Example of the syntax of the svg file itself:  (abridged from it's original 760-line file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="630px" height="891px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:mei="http://www.music-encoding.org/ns/mei" overflow="visible">
   <desc>Engraved by Verovio 4.2.0-dev[undefined]</desc>
   <defs>
      <symbol id="E242-1chrny2" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" overflow="inherit">
         <path transform="scale(1,-1)" d="M206 -748c32 48 49 100 49 149c0 89 -55 168 -168 203c-18 5 -47 9 -87 16v190v190h22c8 0 33 -61 71 -95c4 -3 -2 3 61 -56c62 -58 122 -137 122 -241c0 -32 -7 -65 -17 -96c11 -29 17 -60 17 -94c0 -71 -32 -148 -67 -190c-6 -5 -10 -7 -13 -7s-5 2 -5 5l4 10 c1 3 6 8 11 16zM248 -463c4 18 7 38 7 57c0 105 -80 173 -168 200c-11 3 -27 6 -47 9c9 -17 23 -61 53 -88c4 -3 -2 3 61 -56c36 -33 71 -74 94 -122z" />
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="E050-1chrny2" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" overflow="inherit">
         <path transform="scale(1,-1)" d="M441 -245c-23 -4 -48 -6 -76 -6c-59 0 -102 7 -130 20c-88 42 -150 93 -187 154c-26 44 -43 103 -48 176c0 6 -1 13 -1 19c0 54 15 111 45 170c29 57 65 106 110 148s96 85 153 127c-3 16 -8 46 -13 92c-4 43 -5 73 -5 89c0 117 16 172 69 257c34 54 64 82 89 82 c21 0 43 -30 69 -92s39 -115 41 -159v-15c0 -109 -21 -162 -67 -241c-13 -20 -63 -90 -98 -118c-13 -9 -25 -19 -37 -29l31 -181c8 1 18 2 28 2c58 0 102 -12 133 -35c59 -43 92 -104 98 -184c1 -7 1 -15 1 -22c0 -123 -87 -209 -181 -248c8 -57 17 -110 25 -162 c5 -31 6 -58 6 -80c0 -30 -5 -53 -14 -70c-35 -64 -88 -99 -158 -103c-5 0 -11 -1 -16 -1c-37 0 -72 10 -108 27c-50 24 -77 59 -80 105v11c0 29 7 55 20 76c18 28 45 42 79 44h6c49 0 93 -42 97 -87v-9c0 -51 -34 -86 -105 -106c17 -24 51 -36 102 -36c62 0 116 43 140 85 c9 16 13 41 13 74c0 20 -1 42 -5 67c-8 53 -18 106 -26 159zM461 939c-95 0 -135 -175 -135 -286c0 -24 2 -48 5 -71c50 39 92 82 127 128c40 53 60 100 60 140v8c-4 53 -22 81 -55 81h-2zM406 119l54 -326c73 25 110 78 110 161c0 7 0 15 -1 23c-7 95 -57 142 -151 142h-12 zM382 117c-72 -2 -128 -47 -128 -120v-7c2 -46 43 -99 75 -115c-3 -2 -7 -5 -10 -10c-70 33 -116 88 -123 172v11c0 68 44 126 88 159c23 17 49 29 78 36l-29 170c-21 -13 -52 -37 -92 -73c-50 -44 -86 -84 -109 -119c-45 -69 -67 -130 -67 -182v-13c5 -68 35 -127 93 -176 s125 -73 203 -73c25 0 50 3 75 9c-19 111 -36 221 -54 331z" />
      </symbol>
   </defs>
   <style type="text/css">g.page-margin{font-family:Times,serif;} g.ending, g.fing, g.reh, g.tempo{font-weight:bold;} g.dir, g.dynam, g.mNum{font-style:italic;} g.label{font-weight:normal;}</style>
   <svg class="definition-scale" color="black" viewBox="0 0 21000 29700">
      <g class="page-margin" transform="translate(500, 500)">
         <g id="myw3f4h" class="mdiv pageMilestone" />
         <g id="si7b7ih" class="score pageMilestone" />
         <g id="schrbg5" class="system">
            <path d="M1523 1395 L1523 4072" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="27" />
            <g id="gkn1966" class="grpSym">
               <path d="M1438,4054 C1078,3514 1528,2914 1258,2734 C1591,2914 1141,3514 1438,4054" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="18" />
               <path d="M1438,1413 C1141,1953 1591,2554 1258,2734 C1528,2554 1078,1953 1438,1413" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="18" />
            </g>
            <g id="l1lnivk3" class="label">
               <text x="1105" y="2824" text-anchor="end" font-size="0px">
                  <tspan id="t5bi2fu" class="text">
                     <tspan font-size="405px">Piano</tspan>
                  </tspan>
               </text>
            </g>
            <g id="spkgdb0" class="section systemMilestone" />
            <g id="d1e104" class="measure">
               <g id="ssrt8ln" class="staff">
                  <path d="M1510 3352 L5744 3352" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="13" />
                  <path d="M1510 3532 L5744 3532" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="13" />
                  <path d="M1510 3712 L5744 3712" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="13" />
                  <path d="M1510 3892 L5744 3892" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="13" />
                  <path d="M1510 4072 L5744 4072" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="13" />
                  <g id="c1yswqtr" class="clef">
                     <use xlink:href="#E062-1chrny2" x="1627" y="3532" height="720px" width="720px" />
                  </g>
                  <g id="kf5ls9m" class="keySig">
                     <g id="kzwb8ht" class="keyAccid">
                        <use xlink:href="#E260-1chrny2" x="2308" y="3892" height="720px" width="720px" />
                     </g>
                  </g>
                  <g id="m1xwh8sv" class="meterSig">
                     <use xlink:href="#E082-1chrny2" x="2616" y="3532" height="720px" width="720px" />
                     <use xlink:href="#E084-1chrny2" x="2621" y="3892" height="720px" width="720px" />
                  </g>
                  <g id="l1d0tlud" class="layer">
                     <g id="sjlp4ru" class="space" />
                  </g>
               </g>
               <g id="d1x1taea" class="dir">
                  <text x="3189" y="276" font-size="0px">
                     <tspan id="rk2beft" class="rend">
                        <tspan id="t1x5g3fw" class="text">
                           <tspan font-size="405px">Not fast.</tspan>
                        </tspan>
                     </tspan>
                  </text>
               </g>
               <g id="t5anxs" class="tie">
                  <path d="M4250,1260 C4315,1107 4500,1107 4566,1260 C4473,1154 4342,1154 4250,1260" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="9" />
               </g>
               <g id="t1xucvsx" class="tie">
                  <path d="M4250,2160 C4342,2267 4473,2267 4566,2160 C4500,2314 4315,2314 4250,2160" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="9" />
               </g>
               <g id="b11owwib" class="barLine">
                  <path d="M5731 1395 L5731 2115" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="27" />
                  <path d="M5731 3352 L5731 4072" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="27" />
               </g>
            </g>
...
```

Comment: "And does that still allow for determining the element that is under a mouse event?" you mean something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77569981/how-can-i-create-a-tooth-selection-ui-in-flutter-with-32-teeth#77571625?

Comment: Yeah something like that is a viable option.  I just need to send a call to an API depending on what note is being clicked/dragged

Comment: Viable for dealing with clicks that is, but it doesn't address the drawing issue

Comment: drawing is done in `ToothBorder.paint` method

Comment: Right, but given the complexity of the SVG I'm using, that would be a ton of work (and time to run) to translate every element like that.  There are many technologies that can draw this kind of SVG (like the JS engine), so I'm wondering how to leverage them in Flutter

Comment: as I can tell, you have some XML that is not a standard SVG, that's why flutter-svg fails, am I right? If so you have to parse it somehow

Comment: Well, it is a standard SVG, it's just structured in a more complicated way than the libraries like flutter_svg are built to parse